# Changing collection object values en masse

Tags: java, collections

Is it possible to make changes to all objects in a collection at once?

e.g. (this is impossible):

```
thisCollection.getAll().setTested(true);
```

There is no `getAll` and so I wondered if there was another way to make this change while avoiding iteration.

Comment: Not with instance variables. Class variables however (ie static variables) are perhaps what you seek? ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can use [`Iterable.forEach`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-):

```
thisCollection.forEach(x -> x.setTested(true));
```

That's still going to iterate, of course - there's nothing you can do about that. You've got lots of objects to modify... how would you *expect* them to all be modified without any iteration?

It's up to you whether you view the above as simpler or more complicated than just doing it the "old fashioned" way with an enhanced for loop:

```
for (Item item : thisCollection) {
    item.setTested(true);
}
```